# return iterator from thenReturn mockito

Tags: java, mockito

Hi I have a class `A` implementing `Iterable`.
I have this code to stub an object of this class:

First way:

```
A source = mock(A.class);
final List<String> documents = getList();
when(source.iterator()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Iterator<String>>() {
    @Override
    public Iterator<String> answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        return documents.iterator();
    }
});
```

Second way:

```
A source = mock(A.class);
final List<String> documents = getList();
when(source.iterator()).thenReturn(getList().iterator());
```

The first way returns a new `Iterator` on every call to `source.iterator()` but the second one returns the same `Iterator` object. So if I use second way to stub the source object, I get an empty iterator in subsequent calls to `source.iterator()`.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't Mock return a new `Iterator` on every call to `source.iterator()`?

Comment: If you are concerned about the readability of the first block of code then you should extract the answer in a static factory method, then the code would look like : `when(source.iterator()).then(returnIteratorFrom(documents))` and you will have a function `public static Answer<Iterator<String>> returnIteratorFrom(final Iterable<String>) { return new Answer...; }`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inlining code can sometimes be confusing. Let's unwrap the second block of code:

```
A source = mock(A.class);
final List<String> documents = getList();
final Iterator<String> iter = getList().iterator()
when(source.iterator()).thenReturn(iter);
```

Now, it's easier to understand. The same `iter` object is always returned, and hence it retains it's state. The fact that before the change above mockito had a function call in the brackets is inconsequential - mockito has an object passed to it, which it stores internally, and returns when required. It cannot "remember" that this object was produced by calling a function unless it has the actual code to execute it - for example, like you did in the first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

In complement to what Mureinik stated, this behaviour is actually the normal behaviour of the **when** Mockito method. From [Mockito doc](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39):

> Once stubbed, the method will always return stubbed value regardless
>   of how many times it is called.

Answer (score 0):

A very old question, but here are my 2cents

to stub a generic Iterable, I defined this generic function
inside an utility class:

```java
public class MockUtils {
  public static <T> void whenIterated(Iterable<T> p, T... elem) {
    when(p.iterator()).thenAnswer(a -> List.of(elem).iterator());
   }
}
```

and then if I have to stub A iterating on a list (like `documents`) I use it n this way:

```java
A source = mock(A.class);
MockUtils.whenIterated(source, documents);
```